# How Can I Use Imagick to Change the Color Profile to SRGB and Have it Preserve Colors Like `convert {file} -profile {iccfile} {file}

Tags: php, image-processing, imagemagick, imagick, imagemagick-convert

I'm having an issue converting the color profile from "Display P3" to "sRGB IEC61966-2.1" in Imagick (PHP API Class), and having it preserve the colors of an image the same way it does when running from command line: `convert IMG_1329.jpg -profile sRGB2014.icc testimage.jpg`

```html
<?php

header('Content-type: image/jpeg');

$sRGB_icc = file_get_contents('sRGB2014.icc');
$image = new \Imagick('IMG_1329.jpg');
$image->setImageProfile('icc', $sRGB_icc);
$image->transformImageColorspace(\Imagick::COLORSPACE_SRGB);

echo $image;
```

The original image can be downloaded here:
http://cdn.webplant.media/IMG_1329.jpg

The ICC Color profile used can be downloaded here:
http://cdn.webplant.media/sRGB2014.icc

Here is a screenshot of the different outputs. Notice the vibrant colors in the roof and on the trunk of the tree in the original image, and the image converted with `convert`.

[Original vs Imagick vs Convert](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R4AnR.jpg)

How can I get Imagick to output the same quality image as when using `convert IMG_1329.jpg -profile sRGB2014.icc testimage.jpg`?